# Check if the functional $T$ is a distribution

Tags: complex-analysis

I started complex analysis a few weeks back and we have arrived at the distributions and I was hoping to get some help with some probably elementary exercises to understand the thought process for these kinds of exercises.

a) The exercise goes like this:

Check if the functional $T$ defined by is a distribution

$$\langle{T, φ}\rangle=\int_0^2\ln(x + 1) φ(x) dx$$

I have to find out what type of distribution is **regular** or **delta**

Comment: What’s your definition of distribution/regular/delta? Try to use that.

Comment: So as long as its of the type $\langle{T, φ}\rangle=\int f(x) φ(x) dx$ its a regular?